# PHP - Sorting a table record in ascending order with respect to one of the columns

Tags: php, arrays, columnsorting

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj6Ue.png)

The following code displays a 3-column table with alternating row columns. The columns are company name, file and deadline date (closeDate) from the recruitment table. This is for the front end and admins enter the data in the back-end.

The rows currently show in descending order i.e. the date record with the latest recruitment date is at the top.

I want to modify the code so that the records with the soonest recruitment closeDate show first i.e. in ascending order.

The application is written in cakePHP and I don't want to change the controller.

How can I do it?
Thank you.

```
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead class="blue">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="30%"> Company </th>
                            <th width="50%"> File </th>
                            <th width="20%"> Closing Date </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($recruitments as $key=>$recruitment): ?>
                        <tr class="gradeX <?= $key % 2 == 1 ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>" role="row">
                    <td>
                      <?= !empty($recruitment->Companies['name']) ? $recruitment->Companies['name']:$recruitment->othercompany ?>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                      <?php if($recruitment->pdf): ?>
                        <a href="<?= $this->request->webroot.'uploads/recruitmentfile/'.h($recruitment->pdf); ?>" title="Open File" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg font-red-mint"></i>
                          <?php $file=explode('_',$recruitment->pdf); echo $file[1]?$file[1]:$recruitment->pdf; ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <!--<td><?= h($recruitment->closeDate) ?></td>-->
                    <td><?= $recruitment= date("d F Y", strtotime($recruitment->closeDate)); ?>
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: If  you using a MySQL connection then directly use order by in mysql query OR  if you not using any database connection then user array_sort function.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the exact solution with the code if possible.

Comment: Why don't you want to change the controller? That seems like exactly the right thing to change.

Comment: I prefer not to change the controller because on the admin side I want the descending order.

Comment: It should also separate Admin from public logic into two different controllers. If you do not sort in the controller, there will be inconsistencies in the display of results during pagination.